# Twilio: Multiple outbound conferences at once using one Twilio phone number.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

Just wondering if any Twilio experts can shed some light onto how I might handle having multiple conferences attached to the same Twilio number happening at once.

In the simplest case I would be looking to handle 2 person conferences (so basically just a regular call). 
E.g. lets say I have two 2-person conferences scheduled for 1:00 and those two calls are waiting in a queue to be set up. At 1:00 Twilio would pull the first call from the queue and send out outbound calls to connect User A and User B in the first conference, then it would pull the second call from the queue and send out outbound calls to User C and User D to connect them in a second separate conference. Apart from Twilio’s 1-second per call limit is there anything stopping me from using the same Twilio number to connect both separate conferences?

Is it simply the fact that when my app pulls the second call from the queue it is making separate HTTP requests that keeps the two conferences separate even though they're attached to the same number? I’m working in Rails but I’d appreciate input from anyone as to how I might need to handle that in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Akhil says, there's no limit on making multiple conferences from the same caller id.

What you might do to accomplish this is set a URL parameter in the URL you pass to the create call method that indicates which conference your users will join. For example:

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

client.calls.create(
  :from => YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
  :to => user.phone_number,
  :url => "/conference?conference_room=#{user.current_conference}"
)
```

Then, in your route you can look up the conference name and add the user to it.

```
def conference
  conf_room = params[:conference_room]
  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial do
      r.Conference conf_room
    end
  end
  render :xml => twiml.to_xml
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all!

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation in making multiple conferences at once from the same caller ID. You can have any number of simultaneous calls from the same number at a time (Respecting twilio's 1 call per second limit).

The key here is to have a unique name for a conference and join users to the correct conference.